# Special case of exception handling in Python

Tags: python, exception

I am trying to do some parsing on some text. I have the binary version of the parser to in my program'd body,I use `call` to run this parser and pass my sentences one by one. However, for some reasons sometimes the parser is not able to parse the sentence and generates an error.It might be a bit difficult to put it into words, it just prints some error messages but does not crash and ends normally. My understanding is that there is some sort of exception handling done in the parser itself that it doesn't crash. However, I want to keep track of these problematic sentences. In other words, if the parser couldn't parse the sentence I want to write that sentence in a file. I used the normal exception handling as I do with all of my programs, but it seems it cannot catch exception as the exception has been taken care of inside the parser program. Does anyone know how I should catch these kind of external exception?
thanks

Comment: It might be easier to give advice if you can give some source code.

Answer (score 0):

Check the return code of `call`. Is it any different when you get the exception compared to normal/correct execution? If you want to get an exception you could use `check_call`.

Another solution could be the usage of `check_output` to call the parser-program and examine the output.

Documentation for all functions: [Python subprocess module](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#convenience-functions)